# How to get access to no-existing tag?

Tags: html, dom, tags

If you create following HTML below:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Last1</td>
    <SPAN><FONT>test1</FONT></SPAN>
</tr>
</table>
```

and check DOM model you will see that IE(maybe others) create tag with no-name.

Here is link to screenshot [Screenshot:](http://i464.photobucket.com/albums/rr4/PARUS_UKRAINE/spares/tag.gif)

Are there any possibility to get access to this tag or not ?

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid.
You can only put `<td>` and `<th>` elements directly inside `<tr>`s.

The browser is creating this tag in an attempt to fix your broken markup.

You should correct your HTML.